# What's the best way to access both user audio and user video in the browser without creating multiple confirmation popups?

Tags: javascript, video, browser, navigator

If I call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true})`, then the browser (I used Chrome) creates a single permissions confirmation modal asking if the user wants to grant webcam and mic access. But if either the webcam or mic is not available, perhaps due to the browser not being permissioned to access it, then the entire getUserMedia operation throws an exception, and I can't access either track.

I can try accessing the two separately:

```
try {
  video = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false})
} catch (err) { // whatever };
try {
  audio = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true})
} catch (err) { // whatever };
```

But then I get 2 separate browser confirmation popups, which is suboptimal.

I can avoid both problems by attempting to use the first method and then falling back to the second method if it fails. But is this the best solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check if camera and microphone devices are available on the machine before prompting users. You can do that with the handy `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()`

```js
// Request available media devices.
const mediaDevices = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

// Populate getUserMedia constraints based on available media devices.
let constraints = {};
if (mediaDevices.find(device => device.kind == 'videoinput')) {
  constraints.video = true;
}
if (mediaDevices.find(device => device.kind == 'audioinput')) {
  constraints.audio = true;
}  

const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
```